# Android Manifest Uses Permissions Vs Android Device Specifications

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

Is there any way to check why [my Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.s5.safetylink) doesn't show in `Play Store` on some devices such as `Samsung Galaxy S Duos`, `Samsung Ace Plus` and `Micromax A110` etc. ? While I can install my app via `USB ADB(Eclipse)` on these devices manually. Below are Manifest Uses Permissions :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- for reading contacts -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <!--
     Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

     NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
           where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.s5.safetylink.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.s5.safetylink.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This application has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Can someone provide any link or article where I can tally manifest permissions and device specs to know why my Android App is not compatible with particular device or why it's not showing in Play Store on particular device ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this:http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Generally it states under the  that if your app requires a certain permission that requires certain hardware (e.g Camera) then even if you did not declare it under the  section, google play will filter out your application to devices that do not hold that certain hardware... Hope this helps