# How to figure out why an Android device is not compatible with an APK

Tags: android, apk, manifest, google-play

In the Google Play Developer Console I can check which devices are compatible/supported for my APK. How do I find out why a device is unsupported?

For example, the Google Nexus 7 "tilapia" and "grouper" are not supported. But Nexus 7, Google Nexus 7 "deb" and Google Nexus 7 "flo" are supported.

Is there a way to know which feature in the manifest is causing the problem?

Features:

- android.hardware.CAMERA
- android.hardware.LOCATION
- android.hardware.location.GPS
- android.hardware.location.NETWORK
- android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE
- android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN

API Level 10+

Comment: I also asked same but didn't get any solution yet, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806304/android-manifest-uses-permissions-vs-android-device-specifications

Comment: Is the camera, Tilapia version doesn't have a rear camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>
```

This should help. By default, declared permission are required. Nexus 7 (2012) doesn't have front camera, that's why this device isn't compatible.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#hardware-requirements

Comment: We ended up using the Amazon AppStore ("Amazon underground") to distribute our app to users with a Nexus 7 device with no rear camera. Devices with no rear camera were not ruled out as incompatible like in Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to the lack of a rear camera on older nexus 7s.  The tilapia and grouper are the 2012 version and have no rear camera (only front camera), flo is 2013 and has both types of camera.