# google play says my app is incompatible on certain phones

Tags: android, google-play

I looked up all possibilities for this to be happening, but found no solution. The size of my apk is 7MB, size of the app goes upto 10Mb after installation. I have no bulky files in Raw folder, i have no raw folder at all for that matter. There are no features with requires-true. support all densities is true. support all screens is true. Even then, my app is not listed when searched from some devices, and incompatible on a few other. Why is this happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.app"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="permission_name" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <!-- <uses-feature -->
    <!-- android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" -->
    <!-- android:required="false" /> -->
    <!-- <uses-feature -->
    <!-- android:name="problem feature" -->
    <!-- android:required="false" /> -->

    <application
        android:name="com.application.app.entity.GlobalData"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.SqueakeeMapListViewPager"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ActvityOffersPage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.MainActivityAlt"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ListOffers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.OfferDeatilsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.MerchantActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ActvityReview"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="reviewactvity"
                    android:scheme="squeekee-reviewactivity" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ImageDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppDialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.GetDirection"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="myactivity"
                    android:scheme="squeekee-getDirection" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.updater.WakefulReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="org.application.app.constant.AlarmSetter" />

        <service android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.updater.UpdateService" />
        <service android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.VersionCheckService" />
        <service android:name="org.application.app.constant.ServiceSense" />

        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ListOffersoffers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.BecomeAnOfferChampActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ActivityFeedback"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ActivityOfferAlerts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.application.app.squeakee.ActivityListOfCategories"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: which devices few names ?

Comment: Samsung galaxy start pro GT-S7262 for instance, there might be more.

Comment: are you using fragments.?

Comment: yes i am. but that shouldn't be any issue, should it?

Comment: yes. it doses not supported by api 8

Comment: Even I didn't get answer yet. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806304/android-manifest-uses-permissions-vs-android-device-specifications

Answer (score 0):

may be you are using fragments some where like in google maps that you used, which make your app incompatible because it does not supported by api version 8.see here for api < 11.

[Android - Fragment API for API level < 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176841/android-fragment-api-for-api-level-11)

if you are using fragments only in google maps , then you can use supportfragment.

read here too.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: That is when run on versions below 8, this phone that says is incompatible hosts an Android OS version 4.1 . So i dont think it has anything to do with fragments.

Comment: you title says "app is incompatible on some phones" , thats why i think it might be problem for api < 11.

Comment: i dont think that is the issue. because it runs fine on samsung galaxy  ace with OS version 2.3. The phone that i mentioned(GT-S7262) does not show up in the list of compatible device(or all devices) either.

Comment: @Abby Yes i got the same problem as u got.Can u give me the suggestions to solving this issues

Comment: @Kalai , the compatibility check is handled by Google play store, i tried everything from my end, but yet the app wouldn't list on some devices.

Comment: Guys were you able to solve this? I am seeing this same issue on the (GT-S7262)